# what is the best practice for enqueue bootstrap into WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am learning WordPress theme development and bootstrap. My question is what is the best
practice to enqueue bootstrap into WordPress?.

Using the bootstrap CDN links or downloading the bootstrap min files into your theme folder and enqueue from within the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your use case, If you want to sell the theme to others developers or site owners I would probably copy the min files into the theme folder and enqueue it, as you will have control over the exact used version, you can change voostrap files if needed and don't have to think about the CDN beeing down. Also people might have concerns using a CDN because they have a strict [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) or european users might have issues with GDPR. (a CDN will log some user specific information like IP addresses)

If on the other hand you are developing the theme just for your own page or a single clients page, there might be some good reasons to use a CDN:

> 1. It increases the chance that there will be a cache-hit.
> 2. It ensures that the payload will be as small as possible.
> 3. It reduces the amount of bandwidth used by your server.
> 4. It ensures that the user will get a geographically close response.

In the past, I would have used a CDN but nowadays I'd just require it with npm / yarn and use it locally. (My own opinion)